# Golang crypto/hmac global hash object

Tags: go, sha256, hmac

I try to use global hmac hash for generating signature. Code works well, but generated signature doesn't satisfy 3rd party integration checker. If hmac hash will be created for each 'signature generation' process it will works fine.

Works fine - signature is accepted by 3rd party:

```
func tokenSignatureFunc(key string) tokenSignType {
    signToken := func(token string) []byte {
        h := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte(key))
        h.Write([]byte(token))
        signature := h.Sum(nil)
        base64Signature := make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.EncodedLen(len(signature)))
        base64.StdEncoding.Encode(base64Signature, signature)
        return base64Signature
    }
    return signToken
}
```

Doesn't work - signature is not accepted by 3rd party:

```
func tokenSignatureFunc(key string) tokenSignType {
    h := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte(key))
    signToken := func(token string) []byte {
        h.Write([]byte(token))
        signature := h.Sum(nil)
        base64Signature := make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.EncodedLen(len(signature)))
        base64.StdEncoding.Encode(base64Signature, signature)
        return base64Signature
    }
    return signToken
}
```

Comment: Please explain why the second version should work when you reuse the same hmac for all signatures? The second version is wrong, the first okay. So use the first.

Comment: Ok, at least it should fail with second request (with your point), but it fails with first request. I think that hmac is just generator.. Is not it?

Comment: h.Reset() helps after h.Sum(nil) helps me.

Comment: You did not show show code that demonstrates that the second does not produce the same output than the first. I claim they work the same on first invocation: https://play.golang.org/p/GTtoR6r2kpz . And yes. Reseting the Hash should work.

Comment: Btw: Instead of `h.Write(token); h.Sum(nil)` just do a `h.Sum(token)`.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may be failing due to base64 padding. Use `RawStdEncoding` instead

```
func HMAC256(payload string, secret string) string {
   sig := hmac.New(sha256.New,[]byte(secret))
   sig.Write([]byte(payload))
   return b64Encode(string(sig.Sum(nil)[:]))
}


func b64Encode(text string) string {
   return base64.RawStdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(text))
 }
```